# What are these and how to fix "Could not find layout engine view for view's ..." warnings in Console.app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm starting to work on an existing project and I see a ton of layout warnings in Console.app after app running app from Xcode. The project uses storyboard file and auto layout. App already is tested visually from user interface, but do these warning are trying to tell that there are a lot of duplicated and not-needed constraints? However, these warnings do not contain view names or other useful information, so it would be hard to hunt down them one by one. The only solution I see is to go through the whole app and manually check each constraint.

I'v looked at view controllers in storyboard but they don't contain yellow/red layout IB warnings. Strange, but it looks clean from interface builder side... Here's screenshot of these warnings (there are five times more).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check the last line of warning, for me it looked like this

Users/user/Documents/Dev/MyiOSProject/Project/Project/Supporting Files/Base.lproj/Storyboard.storyboard:dse-nb-xgC: warning: 2 conflicting constraints

The ID at the end identifies the object causing the problem. Right click on storyboard and open as source code, then look for the object with ID e.g. dse-nb-xgC

Look for the container of that line to identify the controller and either go to resolve your problem manually or delete the line and start from there

Comment: This worked for me.
A big problem was that in the Warning Log there's a lot of information about another views, it was very confusing.